# How can I make search result to be in a shortened url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails guides show the following example as a generic search form.

```
<%= form_tag(search_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Things work fine but, if I want to find something that has "251", the resulting url from the above looks like

```
app.com/searches?utf8=✓&keywords=251
```

How should I modify the code such that the resulting url will look something like

```
app.com/searches/251
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about redirecting from the search action if the param[:keywords] exists like this:

```
redirect_to( :action => "searches", :id => params[:keywords] ) and return
```

Depending on how your routes are setup.